# Any methods for clean URIs in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, url, rtsp

URIs like the following are expected in a program:

```
rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/live.sdp/
rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/live.sdp
rtsp://127.0.0.1:554
rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/
rtsp://127.0.0.1:554//live.sdp
```

In the end, I'd like to have only one clean way:

```
rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/live.sdp
```

Where scheme (rtsp://), ip (127.0.0.1), port (554) and path (live.sdp) is submitted separately. So I have to make sure that the path doesn't only contains slashes (/), doesn't start with a slash (/live.sdp), doesn't end with a slash (live.sdp/) and that the URL doesn't end with slashes (rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/) so I can add a slash between URL and path without worrying something will go wrong.

Any easy method to achieve this?

Comment: You can split the `URI` string first by character `/` then you take them one by one. It's the easiest I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class to parse and construct URIs. There's no need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `string split and format`;

```
string s1 = ip + ":" + port + "/" + path;
string[] arr = s1.Split(new string[] { "/" }, 
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string url = scheme + string.Format("{0}/{1}", arr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
var uri = new UriBuilder(String.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}/{3}",protocol,host,port,path)).Uri;
```